# When comparing two classification methods in a Data set, is it important to use the same Training / Testing data set?

Tags: classification

Suppose we wish to compare the efficiency of two classification techniques on a data set (kNN vs SVM for example). We have two options: We can first separate the original data set in two groups: Training vs Testing, train each algorithm on the same training set, and then compare their efficiency on the same testing set, or we can create different training / testing divisions for each of the algorithms, and test their performance on each of their specified pair of Training/Testing data sets.

I think if the samples are independent, both techniques should give the same result. Is this true? Which of both is preferable?

Comment: I assume you mean “efficacy” instead of “efficiency”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Train and test both models using the same data. Otherwise you can’t distinguish between differences because of the models and differences because of the samples.

Your argument about giving the same result would only hold if you take *many* samples and aggregate your measure across these. (This is related to bootstrap resampling.) But you’re only taking one (different) sample for each model.